# Complex zeros of $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s) + \zeta'(1-s)/\zeta(1-s) $ = simpler expression (except at zeta zeros)

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $ G(s) := \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} + \frac{\zeta'(1-s)}{\zeta(1-s)}$
where $s$ is not a zero of zeta.

$G$ has real zeros and a pair of complex zeros near $\frac12 \pm 6i$.

Partial results:

By differentiating $\log{\xi(s)} - \log{\xi(1-s)}$ one gets:

$$ G(s) = -1/2\psi(1/2+s/2)+1/2\pi\tan(\pi s/2) -1/2 \psi(s/2) +\log\pi \qquad (1) $$

when $s$ is not a zeta zeros. Probably (1) can be simplified since
$\Re G(s) = \Re\left(-1/(s-1)+1/s+\log\pi -(\psi(s/2)+\psi((1-s)/2+1)/2\right)$

> Are there other complex zeros of (1), especially in the critical strip?

X-Ray of $G(s)$ using (1):

[image]

Comment: $\xi(s) = \xi(1-s)$, isn't it? What is your definition of $\xi$?

Comment: @plusepsilon.de IIRC it is Riemann xi:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function

Comment: @plusepsilon.de Yes, your equality holds. So by differentiating the logs the expression must be $0$, which how I derived the G(s).

Comment: @plusepsilon.de I meant:  first express xi in terms of zeta and then...

Comment: How do cancel the Euler products? Seems like you only got the $\Gamma$ factor.

Comment: @plusepsilon.de Indeed there is much cancelation. If you express zeta in terms of Siegel Z and theta, $G(s)= -2 \theta'( (s-1/2)/i)$ and this does not depend on $Z$.